# Tracing paper effect

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery

Is it possible to have a tracing paper effects on the top of the image layer like this (See photo). Is there any plugin or JS library that I can look up to? Thanks.

[Sample tracing paper effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZXbj.jpg)

Comment: Are you looking to put as translucent image over another, Or something dynamic?

Comment: I have resolved it now. I just stack the original image and the architectural sketch lines on the top of the original image. I thought this effect is like drawing the sketch line animation with canvas, fortunately it's stacking the images.

Although, if you may know something like this tracing effect animation that sits on the top of the original image (I have no idea if it is possible though) let me know thanks. https://codepen.io/jedl1503/full/bGYPgdO

Comment: Add that as an answer

Comment: If you turn your comment into an answer. Then add a comment to me saying done, then I will up-vote it because it is a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also just edit the image locally before adding to web-server. For an animation, you could create an animation, and add to web-server.